# Is it possible to jump to an outer "case" statement from a nested one?

Tags: scala

Here below is a simple example of how to handle unexpected errors:

```
try {
  // some code that may throw an exception...
} catch {
    case e: MyException => e.errorCode match {
      case Some(ErrorCodes.ERROR_ONE) => println("error 1")
      case Some(ErrorCodes.ERROR_TWO) => println("error 2")
      case _ => println("unhandled error")
      }
    case _ => println("unhandled error")
}
```

As you can see in the code above, both the top level `case` on the exceptions and the nested `case` on the error codes end in a kind of *catch all* to handle unexpected errors. The code works... but I'm wondering whether there is a more elegant way that let me avoid the repetition and have just one *catch all* statement [i.e. `println("unhandled error")`]:

```
try {
  // some code that may throw an exception...
} catch {
    case e: MyException => e.errorCode match {
      case Some(ErrorCodes.ERROR_ONE) => println("error 1")
      case Some(ErrorCodes.ERROR_TWO) => println("error 2")
        // case _ => println("unhandled error")
        // is it possible to jump to the outer *catch all* statement?
      }
    case _ => println("unhandled error")
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to break out of a case statement. But maybe you could make your `MyException` a case class and pattern match on it? Or alternatively, write an extractor for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For only a few cases then you can use `case ... if ...` statement to avoid the nested match as following:

```
try {
  errorThrowingCall()
} catch {
  case e: MyException if e.errorCode == Some(ErrorCodes.ERROR_ONE) => println("error 1")
  case e: MyException if e.errorCode == Some(ErrorCodes.ERROR_TWO) => println("error 2")
  case _ => println("unhandled error")
}
```

Alternatively as @Carsten suggests, just turn your exception into the case class:

```
case class MyException(errorCode : Option[Int]) extends Exception
```

and do pattern matching on it as shown below:

```
try {
  errorThrowingCall()
} catch {
  case MyException(Some(ErrorCodes.ERROR_ONE)) => println("error 1")
  case MyException(Some(ErrorCodes.ERROR_TWO)) => println("error 2")
  case _ => println("unhandled error")
}
```